# Submitting a package to CRAN: .tar.gz file

Tags: r, file, package, tar, cran

I have a package I am ready to submit to CRAN (everything checks out). However, in the spot where it says Choose File, I am unsure what file to choose, as it says it requires a .tar.gz file, which I gather is some kind of compressed file?
Do I need to compress everything into a .tar.gz file? If so, how?

If not, I have a .Rproj file, and various files like namespace and description and license, so it is unclear to me which file to submit.

I apologize if this is a simple question, this is my first package to be submitted.

Comment: Do you know about the `R CMD build ...` command?  Have you found the 'Build Source Package' menu option in RStudio?

Comment: I have built the package using the "build and reload" button, is that not right?

Comment: It is not.  Try to regroup with one of the _numerous_ tutorials on package building.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options here.  Use R's command line command:

```
> R CMD build /path/to/package/directory
```

Or use `devtools::build` from *within* R:

```
R> devtools::build( "path/to/package/directory" )
```

Both result in a `tar.gz` file on your local file system. The name will look like: `mypackage_[Version].tar.gz`

It is this file that you load to CRAN.

Comment: Oef saved me so much trouble once I found this